# how does laravel eloquent model works?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

in db `Seller table` and this table have `seller_id` and i have column `paid` and i want to get that data using model so consider in controller i use

```
$seller = User::all();
```

in `User Model`

```
public function benefits(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Seller' , 'seller_id');
}
```

in view

```
@foreach($sellers as $key => $seller)
    <td>{{ $seller->benefits->paid}}<\td>
@endforeach
```

**but problem is that i am unable to get value from column paid in seller table my result is null how this query will work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There is no `$sellers` variable in your code.
- `$seller` is a collection, not a single record.
- Eager load `benefits` relationship to avoid making too many queries.

```
$sellers = User::with('benefits')->all();
```

```xml
@foreach ($sellers as $seller)
    <td>{{ $seller->benefits->paid }}<\td>
@endforeach
```

If `seller_id` is a column in the `Seller` model's table, then the `benefits` relationship in the `User` model is either `hasOne` or `hasMany`

```
// User Model
public function benefits()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Seller', 'seller_id');
}
```

```
// Seller Model
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'seller_id');
}
```

Comment: thanx for contribution i already use ($sellers as $seller) i forgot to post here but it doesnot work

Comment: Is `seller_id` a column in your `users` table?

Comment: seller_id is a column in Seller table

Comment: Then the relationship isn't `User` belongsTo `Seller`. It's either `User` hasOne `Seller` or `User` hasMany `Seller`

Comment: oh thanx for your help i am week in model concept only it is worked for me:)

Comment: You're welcome. Here is [some documentation on the subject](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)